# How to move left all shapes in a workbook except for one of them

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make VBA move left all the shapes in all the sheets of my workbook, except for one shape of them. I was able to do the coding to move all shapes left, but when I tried to add the exception, it is not working. Can anyone help me out? This is the coding I did (I am just beginning to use VBA):

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SP As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Activate
    For Each SP In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
        If SP.Name <> "Rectangle 10" Then
            Selection.Left = 100
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need to activate the sheet before looping through the drawing objects for that sheet.  Secondly, you should use the object variable `SP` to set the Left property.  Therefore, assuming that the target workbook is the active workbook, try the following...

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SP As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each SP In ws.DrawingObjects
            If SP.Name <> "Rectangle 10" Then
                SP.Left = 100
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works well, the only thing is that I actually need several shapes to move by the same distance. I mean I have several shapes in several columns, and I need them to move horizontally all by the same distance. Using this solution they all end up in the the same column, so some of them end up moving longer than others. I have tried several things, it seems the incrementleft function does not work with an object. I have also used .left and I cannot make that work either. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!